# Adding a EventHandler function to button click event with sender as a parameter

Tags: f#, eventhandler

Adding a EventHandler function to button click event with sender as a parameter.

```
let ButtonClicked (evArgs)= 
     DoSomthing...

button.Click.Add(fun evArgs -> ButtonClicked())
```

Code Works But I want to somthing like this

```
let ButtonClicked (evArgs,sender)= 
     sender.DoSomthing()
     ...

button.Click.Add(fun evArgs,sender -> ButtonClicked())
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
let ButtonClicked evArgs sender =
    // Do something interesting here
    ()

button.Click.Add(fun evArgs -> ButtonClicked evArgs button)
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Full example. Paste this into the interpreter:

```
open System.Windows.Forms

let form = new Form(Text = "Form")
let button = new Button(Text = "Button") 
form.Controls.Add(button)

let ButtonClicked sender evargs = 
    printfn "From '%A' received '%A'" sender evargs
button.Click.AddHandler (new System.EventHandler(ButtonClicked))

Application.Run(form)
;;
```

(By the way, how cool is it you can just paste that into the interpreter?)

Comment: Error 1 Type mismatch. Expecting a
    obj -> System.EventArgs -> unit    
but given a
    obj -> System.EventArgs -> 'a -> unit    
The type 'unit' does not match the type ''a -> unit'

Comment: It looks like you used a "ButtonClicked" which takes an extra argument (maybe because you adapted it from one suiting Mark's answer?). I updated the answer to be a self-contained example.

Comment: It's even more cool when you can run it in the interpreter. I've edited your answer accordingly.